# XSLT indexing based on output, not input

Tags: xslt

I have some source XML containing different elements that get transformed by a stylesheet into output elements with the same name. The output elements then require an 'index' element on each one.
My first choice was using position(), but of course that only works for the context of the xsl:for-each in which they're positioned.

Here is a sample XML:

```
<Root>
    <TypeA Val="First Value"/>
    <TypeA Val="Second Value"/>
    <NotToBeTransformed Val="ignoreme"/>
    <TypeB Val="Third Value"/>
    <TypeB Val="Fourth Value"/>
</Root>
```

And here is how I would like it to be rendered as output:

```
<Output>
    <Destination>
        <Index>1</Index>
        <Content>First Value</Content>
    </Destination>
    <Destination>
        <Index>2</Index>
        <Content>Second Value</Content>
    </Destination>
    <Destination>
        <Index>3</Index>
        <Content>Third Value</Content>
    </Destination>
    <Destination>
        <Index>4</Index>
        <Content>Fourth Value</Content>
    </Destination>
</Output>
```

My simple XSLT is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Output>
        <xsl:for-each select="//TypeA">
            <Destination>
                <Index><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></Index>
                <Content><xsl:value-of select="@Val"/></Content>
            </Destination>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="//TypeB">
            <Destination>
                <Index><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></Index>
                <Content><xsl:value-of select="@Val"/></Content>
            </Destination>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>
```

But that outputs the Index with values of 1 and 2 for each of the collections of source elements.
Can this be done in XSLT or would this need to be processed again? I'm doing the transform with C# code, so I could run an initial transform and then set the Index values in code afterwards.

Any help would be most gratefully accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `xsl:for-each` at all (try always to avoid it), neither it is necessary to process `TypeA` and `TypeB` elements separately.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Output>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="TypeA|TypeB"/>
  </Output>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <Destination>
        <Index><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></Index>
        <Content><xsl:value-of select="@Val"/></Content>
    </Destination>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Root>
    <TypeA Val="First Value"/>
    <TypeA Val="Second Value"/>
    <NotToBeTransformed Val="ignoreme"/>
    <TypeB Val="Third Value"/>
    <TypeB Val="Fourth Value"/>
</Root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Output>
   <Destination>
      <Index>1</Index>
      <Content>First Value</Content>
   </Destination>
   <Destination>
      <Index>2</Index>
      <Content>Second Value</Content>
   </Destination>
   <Destination>
      <Index>3</Index>
      <Content>Third Value</Content>
   </Destination>
   <Destination>
      <Index>4</Index>
      <Content>Fourth Value</Content>
   </Destination>
</Output>
```

Comment: That's a very valid answer for my sample XML, but I think perhaps I made my sample too simple!
The elements I want to transform into indexed output are many and varied, and buried within many other elements, so using `match="*/*"`is unfortunately not a valid solution for me.

Comment: Pondering your answer - could I call the same template separately for the elements I want (in a way similar to yours) and use the `position()` function within that?

Comment: @MattJones: In this case it is most appropriate to edit/update the question with more realistic data. Please.

Comment: I've added an element that sits in the middle of the elements to be transformed, that should not appear in the output or affect the indexing in the output. I hope that helps.

Comment: @MattJones: See my updated answer -- now processing your latest-provided XML :)

Comment: @DimitriNovatchev Your answer has inspired me to use a named template that can be called for the elements that I require, passing in the source elements in parameters. Many, many thanks for putting me on the right path! +1 to your answer!

Comment: @MattJones: On another note, I strongly recommend *to avoid as much as possible* using named templates and/or `xsl:for-each`. These are very rarely necessary and their use makes it difficult for a novice XSLT programmer to get used to the functional, non-imperative nature of the language and to its fundamental pattern-matching architecture.

Comment: @DimitriNovatchev I will see if I can rewrite my XSL to use the pattern matching architecture as you have explained. If I have difficulty, no doubt you will see another question from me! ;)

Comment: @MattJones: I wouldn't put too much effort into that, there really is nothing wrong with using named templates; there's numerous examples of how they can make your XSLT much simpler and more readable/maintainable. Despite what Dimitre might preach, XSLT is *NOT* a functional language, it's declarative; functional languages are a subset of declarative ones, and while it's possible to use XSLT in a purely functional style, it's by no means necessary.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Was Phill Wadler "preaching" that XSLT is a functional language? The year: 2002 (even then). The conference: Summer School of Advanced Functional Programming. The venue: Oxford, UK. It is *you* who seems to be preaching -- on topics that you, most probably, don't understand better than Phill Wadler. You may bother to read the Last Call of XPath 3.0 and think again whether XSLT is functional or not...

Comment: Actually, Phil was talking about XQuery: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~jeuri101/afp/afp4/xquery-afp.pdf From the proverbial horses mouth, however: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xslt/#h33882. Anyway, you've proven to be incapable of civilized debate so I will not waste my time or anyone elses discussing it further.

Comment: @Flynn1179: I was in the room when Phil said this, so I don't have to read a deformed account of the conference :) And if by "civilized debate" you mean tolerating false statements, then yes, I am incapable of such "civilized debate" :)